# ¿Cómo puedo encriptar una contraseña en Java?

Tags: php, java, mysql

tengo un sistema web con registro y loggin, en el cual yo cree el usuario admin y encripte la contraseña de tal manera:

```
    $encriptar = crypt($_POST["ingPassword"], '$2a$07$asxx54ahjppf45sd87a5a4dDDGsystemdev$');
```

Y estoy creando un software en Java con el cual yo pueda logearme igualmente, pero no sabría como igual las password, ya que al momento de colocar los datos me valida la contraseña con el mi base de datos, que creé y encripte con php:

```
    public void validarUser() {
    int result = 0;
    String userName = InputUser.getText();
    String password = String.valueOf(inputPassword.getPassword());
    String sqlQuerry = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" + userName + "'";
    String sqlQuerryPass = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '" + userName + "'  AND password = '" + password + "'";
    try {
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlQuerry);
        if (rs.next()) {
            //Usuario Existe
            Statement stp = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rsp = stp.executeQuery(sqlQuerryPass);
            System.out.println(password);
            if (rsp.next()) {
                result = 1;
                if (result == 1) {
                    AppLM sistema = new AppLM();
                    sistema.setVisible(true);
                    this.dispose();
                }

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contraseña erronea!");
            }

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Su usuario no existe!");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿No se te hace posible crear un servicio rest que encripte lo que desea y mediante Java invocar este método que encripta? Lo comento ya que es realmente imposible determinar la codificación que aplica PHP al obtener el hash

Comment: Primero debes validar el pasdword mediante algun algoritmo, segundo para encriptacion hay varios tipos como bycript md5 etc..., debes buscar alguno que sea compatible en ambos lenguajes